# Standard c++ header not found in Xcode 11.4

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, xcode11.4

I got error for below code in Xcode 11.4

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Please see attach image
[image]

I already copied c++ from Xcode 9.4 to Xcode 11.4 as described in below image

[image]

Still getting error. Please help me.

Comment: `I already copied c++ from Xcode 9.4 to Xcode 11.4` sounds like a mistake. You really should install in the proper manner instead of simply copying stuff around.

Comment: @john please tell me how to properly install c++ in Xcode 11.4

Comment: Sorry I have no idea, but I do know that's what you should do. You also might need to undo any damage caused by copying stuff without properly installing.

Comment: Yeah wipe `/Applications/Xcode.app` and re-install.  C++ is installed by default with Xcode.

Comment: I just added `#include <stdlib.h>` to a C++ project on Xcode 11.4 and it compiled OK.

Comment: for me new cocos2dx compile but old cocos2dx project giving error..so someone suggested c++ fix https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106114   still its not working

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: It might help, but it's still perfectly legal to include <stdlib.h> in C++.

Comment: now its giving error for #include <string> please tell me fix for this

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25716210)